# React with Emotion NPM package gives TypeError

Tags: reactjs, npm, emotion

The goal is to successfully import and use the published npm package from [this repository](https://github.com/shertu/blinq-image-editor) into [this Next.js application.](https://github.com/shertu/emotion-demo)

While the Next.js application does compile, the application produces a runtime error which states:

```bash
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'registered' of null

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/blinq-image-editor@1.0.4_hbkw2sf35pylg2cvgnw53hddsi/node_modules/blinq-image-editor/dist/index.js (2:238027)
Styled(div)
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/blinq-image-editor@1.0.4_hbkw2sf35pylg2cvgnw53hddsi/node_modules/blinq-image-editor/dist/index.js (2:147434)
renderWithHooks
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderForwardRef
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5842:18)
renderElement
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6005:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderElement
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5971:9)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///Users/shertu/shertu/apple/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
```

I code and maintain both repositories so I am able to make configuration changes if necessary. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to avoid SSR.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ImageEditor = dynamic(
  async () => (await import("blinq-image-editor")).ImageEditor,
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```